# Folder Action to Import Files into iTunes doesn't work

Tags: itunes, finder, automator, folder-action

I'm downloading a large number of mp3 files to a folder using `wget` (which is very fast).

I want to add each new file to an iTunes playlist, and therefore set up a Folder Action in *Automator* to do this. I have tried following instructions available here and there, but can't seem to get it to work properly. It did add two files to iTunes, but then gave up – and I can't get it to work again.

Is the fact that `wget` is dowloading lots of files very fast, something that throws the Folder action off?

I've searched around for help with this specific issue but can't seem to find anything except an unanswered [Apple forum post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2368480?tstart=0) where a user is trying to use an AppleScript to do the same thing.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Ok, working with Folder Actions was a slight headache so I downloaded [Hazel](https://www.noodlesoft.com/) which handles all added files swifty. It costs money but it also can do some other things I realized I needed done. But if you know the answer using Automator/AppleScript please post for the sake of completion...